# Why top and left part of input element appear darker than other sides?

Tags: css

I am applying this simple css on an input element for it to have a uniform, thin border which is lightgray in color, on ALL sides. However, I find that two of the sides appear darker ? or it is a shadow property of some kind ? What can be done to make it uniform on all sides ?

```css
input {
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `border-style: solid'

Comment: @Alohci Works! Please add that as an answer, will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `border-style` on input elements is usually `inset`. You need to set it to `solid`.

Actually it usually makes sense to use the [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) shorthand and always set width, color and style at the same time:

```
border: lightgray thin solid;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that because of the 3d effect of the input field.
If you want to remove that 3d effect, just add `border-style: solid;` to your input css.

```css
input {
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<input>
```